# Trying to import csv into MySQL with pymysql and Python version 3

Tags: python-3.x, pymysql

I want to put a simple csv into a MySQL table in a database. I know there are probably other ways to do this but for the system I have in place, I would like to stick with this method if possible.

I have read every other possible post about this and tried many of the suggestions but I can't get it to work. I can get it to work with python 2 but not in 3.

csv is

```
test1   test2
43.49   654.32
78.89   294.95
```

I can't seem to get the syntax correct and get various errors when I try different approaches.

```
import csv 
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect( host = '###.###.##.#',
      user = 'test',passwd = 'test')
cursor = db.cursor()
csv_data = csv.reader('c:/tmp/sample.csv')
next(csv_data)
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO test.table(test1, test2) VALUES(%s, %s)',row)

db.commit()
cursor.close()
print (Imported)
```

Any ideas???

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I can get it to work if i put in actual values like the following. So i just need the syntax for pulling from a csv or txt file. `cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test.table(test1, test2) VALUES('78.25', '90')"""`

Comment: I figured it out. Add the `open` in the following `csv_data = csv.reader(open('c:/tmp/sample.csv'))` and then remove row at the end of `cursor.execute` statement.

Comment: Maybe you should answer your own question with the working example and accept it so that people having the same problem can see how you solved it when they do a search on SO...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, this worked for me:

```
import csv 
import pymysql
db = pymysql.connect( host = '###.###.##.#',
      user = 'test',passwd = 'test')
cursor = db.cursor()
f = csv.reader(open('c:/tmp/sample.csv'))
sql = """INSERT INTO test.table(test1,test2) VALUES(%s,%s)"""
next(f)
for line in f:
    line=[None if cell == '' else cell for cell in line]
    cursor.execute(sql, line)

db.commit()
cursor.close()
print ("Imported")
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked

```
import pymysql
import csv
db = pymysql.connect("localhost","root","12345678","data" )

cursor = db.cursor()
csv_data = csv.reader(open('test.csv'))
next(csv_data)
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO PM(col1,col2) VALUES(%s, %s)',row)

db.commit()
cursor.close()
```